# how to assign string variable to datable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have to assign string variable to datatable.
`dtHistoryList.Rows[1].ItemArray[3] = txtNaiyo.Text;`
It doesn't work. Please Help me.

Comment: Who filling in DataTable? Could you update this value before populating a DataTable?

Answer (score 1):

Use the indexer

```
dtHistoryList.Rows[1][3] = txtNaiyo.Text
```

or

```
dtHistoryList.Rows[1]["rowName"] = txtNaiyo.Text
```